# Dúvida com customização de rotas asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou estudando sobre rotas, tenho uma lista e quero mostra o nome do produto na url. Da forma que está mostra apenas o nome da Categoria.

Agradeço

```
 public class Produto
    {
        public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Categoria { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
        public decimal Preco { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }


        public List<Produto> TodosProdutos()
        {
            var produtos = new List<Produto>
            {
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 110,
                    Categoria = "Informatica",
                    Nome = "Notebook Acer",
                    Descricao = "E5-571-54MC com Intel Core i5, 4GB de RAM, Windows 8.1",
                    Preco = 1690.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,15)
                },
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 120,
                    Categoria = "Informatica",
                    Nome = "Notebook Positivo Premium",
                    Descricao = "TV S6050 LCD 14’’ Processador Intel Core i3, Windows 8, HD 500GB",
                    Preco = 1290.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,1)
                },
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 130,
                    Categoria = "Informatica",
                    Nome = "iPad Mini 3",
                    Descricao = "16 GB Wi Fi Dourado MGYE2BR/A Apple",
                    Preco = 1990.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,10)
                },
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 210,
                    Categoria = "Eletrodomesticos",
                    Nome = "Ar Condicionado Consul",
                    Descricao = "Portátil 12.000 Btus Frio C1A12AB, 220 V, Branco",
                    Preco = 990.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,11)
                },
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 220,
                    Categoria = "Eletrodomesticos",
                    Nome = "Micro-Ondas LG",
                    Descricao = "30 L, EasyClean MH7093R Prata, com Grill, Branco",
                    Preco = 430.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,6)
                },
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 230,
                    Categoria = "Eletrodomesticos",
                    Nome = "Refrigerador Electrolux",
                    Descricao = "DF42 382 Litros 2 Portas Frost Free, 220 V , Branco",
                    Preco = 1250.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,7)
                },
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 310,
                    Categoria = "Telefonia",
                    Nome = "Samsung Galasy S6",
                    Descricao = "SM-G920I Single Chip, Branco, Processador quad-core",
                    Preco = 2120.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,3)
                },
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 320,
                    Categoria = "Telefonia",
                    Nome = "Motorola Moto G",
                    Descricao = "Preto, TV Digital, Dual Chip, Processador Quad Core 1.2GHz, Tela 5",
                    Preco = 870.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,16)
                },
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 410,
                    Categoria = "Esporte",
                    Nome = "Bicicleta Colli Bike ",
                    Descricao = "Aro 26 18 Marchas Suspensão Dianteira CBX 750 Preta + Garrafa Térmica",
                    Preco = 380.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,9)
                },
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 420,
                    Categoria = "Esporte",
                    Nome = "Tênis Feminino Fila",
                    Descricao = "Kenya Racer, 2.0 W Vermelho/Limão, 38, Palminha durável",
                    Preco = 125.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,10)
                },
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 430,
                    Categoria = "Esporte",
                    Nome = "Tênis Diadora",
                    Descricao = "Ghost III Azul e Verde Masculino, número 44",
                    Preco = 65.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,11)
                },
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 510,
                    Categoria = "Beleza",
                    Nome = "Barbeador Philips",
                    Descricao = "Aquatouch AT751 Recarregável, 110 V",
                    Preco = 219.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,1)
                },
                new Produto
                {
                    ProdutoId = 520,
                    Categoria = "Beleza",
                    Nome = "Secador Candence",
                    Descricao = "Secador de Cabelo - SEC400 - 1400w, Cabo, 220 V",
                    Preco = 205.00M,
                    Data = new DateTime(2015,7,3)
                },
            };
            return produtos;
        }
    }
```

tenho no RouteConfig:

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                  "Produtos",
                  "Produtos/",
                  new { Controller = "Produto", Action = "Index" }
                );


            routes.MapRoute(
                "Detalhes",
                "Produtos/{produtoid}",
                new { Controller = "Produto", Action = "Detalhes" },
                new { Produtoid = @"\d+" }
                );


            routes.MapRoute(
                 "Categorias",
                 "Produtos/{categoria}",
                 new { controller = "Produto", action = "Categorias" }
             );


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Produto", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


        }
```

Tenho o Controller:

```
    public class ProdutoController : Controller
    {

        private readonly List<Produto> todosProdutos;



        public ProdutoController()
        {
            todosProdutos = new Produto().TodosProdutos().OrderBy(x => x.Preco).ToList();
        }


        // GET: Produto
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Produtos = "Todos os Produtos";
            return View(todosProdutos);

        }

        public ActionResult Detalhes(int produtoId)
        {
            return View(todosProdutos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProdutoId == produtoId));
        }

        public ActionResult Categorias(string categoria)
        {
            var _categoria = todosProdutos.Where(x => x.Categoria == categoria).ToList();
            ViewBag.Categoria = categoria;
            return View(_categoria);
        }

    }
```

Comment: em qual url q vc quer mostrar o nome do produto?

Comment: qual o problema?

Comment: Quero mostra o nome do produto na URL neste exemplo só mostra o nome da categoria

Answer (score 0):

No seu controller você precisará criar uma action que receba o nome da categoria e do produto como parâmetros. Ex.

```
    public ActionResult Exibir(string categoria, string produto)
    {
        var modelProduto = todosProdutos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Categoria == categoria && x.Nome == produto); //Sugestão, crie um campo para exibir o nome do produto formatado para url: 
        return View(modelProduto );
    }
```

No arquivo RouteConfig.cs adicione a nova configuração. Ex.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Exibir",
    "Produto/{categoria}/{produto}",
    new { Controller = "Produto", Action = "Exibir" }
    );
```

Sugestão: Crie um campo específico no seu modelo para guardar o nome do produto e da categoria de forma "amigável" para URLs, removendo espaços, acentos e caracteres especiais. Ex. Se o nome do produto `"Produto em promoção"`, o campo UrlAmigavel deve trazer `"produto-em-promocao"`.